# How can I work with c++ language in visual studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have tried to run a c++ program in visual studio 2015 environment ,but it doesn't work and it shows me this pop-up window ( Unable to start program 'C:\Path...' . The system cannot find the file specified. ) .

I work with c# language in visual studio 2015 and it's fine , but with c++ it's not . There is 'Local Windows Debugger' button instead of ' Start' button .
[image]
I hope I could explain my problem and I hope you help me . 
 thank you in advance .

Comment: I'd say that it's your naming of the source file (`test c++ .cpp.cpp`) that confuses good ol' VS2015, but I'm not confident enough to make that an answer.

Comment: Try not to have space in your file, use underscore if you need to.  It's best to name your file with alpha numeric sometime with underscore and hypen, and refrain from using other special characters.  Different language and compiler/interpreter can use other characters in your file name, but alpha numeric should work in most case if not all.

Comment: I edit my question , I hope you understand it now 
and thank you .

Comment: I might be the antivirus

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm new here so I'm sorry I can not use this website right .
How can I put the picture on my question ?

Comment: @AhdA.Karman That's ok. I thought you did it on purpose :-) The picture is back. (there's a little _add picture_ button above the edit box)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you . Can you help me in my problem :/ ?

Comment: In the output window of your screenshot you see that the build failed. You should fix that build failure

Comment: @AhdA.Karman You're welcome! I can't help with more hints than I perhaps did with my initial guess (that I made in the top comment). I don't have VS2015 anymore so I can't verify it I'm afraid.

Comment: @UnholySheep Yeah it seems like that , do you know how can I fix it ?

Comment: No because the popup is obscuring the details. Some file you are referencing in your build can not be found, but the details of that you have to read from the error in the build output

Comment: @AhdA.Karman Name your file `hello.cpp`, without spaces, without any special characters, etc.  Then see if that works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project with only ASCII letters in the project name and only ASCII letters in the source file name (e.g. `mytest.cpp`).

Comment: @AhdA.Karman I'm afraid we're all going to need _a lot_ more information than that. You must have gotten a different error message at least? What was it?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2015 does not install C++ support by default. You have to select it in the Custom setup. See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/setup-changes-in-visual-studio-2015-affecting-c-developers/).

> This was a partial step towards the 'new setup experience' in [Visual Studio 2017](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-lightweight-visual-studio-15-installer/) and later that's a lot less confusing and does a better job of keeping the disk footprint down to the portion that the developer actually needs. That said, the "UWP workload" also doesn't include C++ tools by default, you have to add "C++ tools for UWP" if targeting UWP with C++.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time of searching , finally I found the solution to my problem in someone comment on Youtube .

This is the quotation of the comment :

" 
if you didnt install C++ tools or it doesnt show up in your project menu: Go to control panel-> click change on microsoft visual studio -> click modify -> select c++ under languages " .

Thank you all :) ,,